# Integration Testing KafkaListener - confirm that a message was consumed by Listener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hey all (hopefully the legend Gary Russell)

I am trying to write some integration test for a Kafka Listener that I have with the intent of confirming that my KafkaListener would be able to consume a message sent by my producer.

Here is my test suite where I am failing on the assertion check.

```
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {TOPIC})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {KafkaIntegrationTestConfiguration.class}
)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class KafkaIntegrationTest {
  @Inject
  private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

  @Inject
  private KafkaTemplate<String, Event> producer;

  @SpyBean
  private CustomKafkaConsumer consumer;

  @Test
  public void testKafkaListener() throws Exception {

    // initialize listener container
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container =
      (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("custom-consumer");
    container.stop();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Event> messageListener =
        (AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Event>) container
        .getContainerProperties().getMessageListener();
    // create CountDownLatch
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // wrap KafkaListener
    container.getContainerProperties()
      .setMessageListener(new AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Event>() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, Event> data, Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                              Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
          try {
            messageListener.onMessage(data, acknowledgment, consumer);
          } finally {
            latch.countDown();
          }
        }

      });

    container.start();

    // send event to kafka
    sendToKafkaTemplate();

    assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
  }
```

My explicit Producer is configured as :

```
@EnableKafka
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = {TOPIC})
@Import({ KafkaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("..kafkaConfiguration")
@ComponentScan("..kafka")
public class KafkaIntegrationTestConfiguration {
  @Value("${kafka.mainClusterSchemaRegistry}")
  private String schemaRegistry;

  @Bean
  private KafkaTemplate<String, Event> customKafkaTemplate(EmbeddedKafkaBroker ekb) {

    Map<String, Object> config = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(ekb);

    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
    config.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistry);

    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Event> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);

    KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(factory);
    kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(TOPIC);
    return kafkaTemplate;
  }
}
```

One hint that I'm hoping would be useful is that I've made an attempt at placing a breakpoint into the onMessage overwritten function and it never reaches there.

Any clues / suggestions on what to look into?

PS here is my KafkaListenerFactory - omitting KafkaListener class since its pretty bare-bone annotation with topics configured

```
  @Bean(name = LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_NAME)
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event>
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory(SslConfig sslConfig, KafkaConfig kafkaConfig) {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

    final ConsumerFactory<String, Event> consumerFactor =
        consumerFactory(sslConfig, kafkaConfig);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactor);

    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    // need to update to use new Error Handler
    factory.setErrorHandler(buildListenerErrorHandler());

    return factory;
  }


  @KafkaListener(
      id = "sync-consumer",
      topics = TOPIC,
      groupId = GROUP_ID,
      containerFactory = LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_NAME
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do something in that `@KafkaListener` method. And it would be great if you call some service. So, probably much easier to have bean as a `@SpyBean` and Spring Boot Testing framework would inject it properly to your component with the `@KafkaListener`. Then you *spy* its method and verify in the end. You might still need a `CountDownLatch` since consumption happens on the other thread. Or you can just Awaitility for loop until verification on the spy is OK.

Comment: Hey Artem, thanks for the response! Im not entirely following. I currently have my KafkaListener component annotated with a @SpyBean. So what do you mean by "have bean as a SpyBean and Spring Boot Testing framework would inject it properly to your component with the KafkaListener"

Comment: Right. So, make a stub for that `@KafkaListener` method in your test for the future verification.

Comment: I see, so are you suggesting something like this : 
```
    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
      invocation.callRealMethod();
      latch.countDown();
      return null;
    }).when(consumer).consume(any(), any());
``

Comment: Yes, but I don't know your `@KafkaListener` method signature.